# Why do I recieve a 404 Not found error ( with CL and Postman ) from a REST GET on localhost:8080(correct port)

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I've been trying to GET Request an Array from an SPA running on my localhost:8080, which has to be the right port, because its told in the console aswell as if I try to Request other ports it(Postman) says it failed to do the Request. I am having trouble finding the cause for the 404 because I have no errors that I can work with.

Rest Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private AtomicInteger rCounter;
    private AtomicInteger pCounter;
    private List<Registration> registrationList = new ArrayList<Registration>();
    private List<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<Project>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        this.rCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        this.pCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    }

    // THIS SECTION IS DEDICATED TO THE REGISTRATION REQUESTS

    // get all Registrations
    @GetMapping("/registrations")
    public List<Registration> getAllRegistrations() {
        return this.registrationList;
    }

    // get a single Registration
    @GetMapping("/registrations/{id}")
    public Registration getRegistration(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        for (Registration reg : registrationList) {
            if (reg.getId() == id) {
                return reg;
            }
        }

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                String.format("Registration with ID %s not found!", id));
    }

    // create a Registration
    @PostMapping("/createRegistration")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createRegistration(@Valid @RequestBody Registration requestBody) {
        Registration reg = new Registration(rCounter.getAndIncrement(), requestBody.getStudents(),
                requestBody.getPreferredProjects());
        this.registrationList.add(reg);
    }

    // update a Registration
    @PutMapping("/updateRegistration/{id}")
    public void updateRegistration(@PathVariable("id") int id, @Valid @RequestBody Registration requestBody) {
        requestBody.setId(id);
        for (Registration reg : registrationList) {
            if (reg.getId() == id) {
                this.registrationList.set(id, requestBody);
            }
        }

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                String.format("Registration with ID %s not found!", id));
    }

    // delete a Registration
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteRegistration/{id}")
    public void deleteRegistration(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        for (Registration reg : registrationList) {
            if (reg.getId() == id) {
                this.registrationList.remove(id);
            }
        }

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                String.format("Registration with ID %s not found!", id));

    }

    // THIS SECTION IS DEDICATED TO THE PROJECT REQUESTS

    // get all Projects
    @GetMapping("/projects")
    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        return this.projectList;
    }

    // get a single Project
    @GetMapping("/projects/{id}")
    public Project getProject(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        for (Project project : projectList) {
            if (project.getId() == id) {
                return project;
            }
        }

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, String.format("Project with ID %s not found!", id));
    }

    // create a Project
    @PostMapping("/createProject/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createProject(@Valid @RequestBody Project requestBody) {
        Project project = new Project(pCounter.getAndIncrement(), requestBody.getName());
        this.projectList.add(project);
    }

    // update a Project
    @PutMapping("/updateProject/{id}")
    public void updateProject(@PathVariable("id") int id, @Valid @RequestBody Project requestBody) {
        requestBody.setId(id);
        for (Project project : projectList) {
            if (project.getId() == id) {
                this.projectList.set(id, requestBody);
            }
        }

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, String.format("Project with ID %s not found!", id));
    }

    // delete a Project
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteProject/{id}")
    public void deleteProject(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

        for (Project project : projectList) {
            if (project.getId() == id) {
                this.projectList.remove(id);
            }
        }

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, String.format("Project with ID %s not found!", id));

    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of the Request and the Response(404) in Postman]

The Api Bean:

```
// enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            // allow CORS requests for all resources and HTTP methods from the frontend
            // origin
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

If you need to see more just write a comment and i'll provide it through an edit.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have any RequestMapping at the class level. Please post the complete class of the Rest controller.

Comment: Your code says "registrations", yet your screenshot is calling "registration"?

Comment: oh yeah sorry for that @schrom i renamed it the problem stayed its both registrations now

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? Of so i nclude the package declaration of the controller and add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. If not add your configuration for bootstrapping the dispatcher servlet and how you detect controllers.

Comment: Yeah I use Spring Boot (Spring initializer: https://start.spring.io/), but i am very new to the topic so dont really understand what exactly I should include to the ApiApplication(the @SpringBootApplication annotated class)?

Comment: I dont quite understand. So basically I got a Folder in which 2 packages are located one got the RestController(named: backend) and the other got the @SpringBootApplication. Should I add a package backend to the annotated class or what is required?